# How can I keep the terminal open?

Tags: windows-xp, terminal

I'm using a terminal application in Windows XP.

I set it as favorite application for files with a specific extension.

So now when I click on a file, the terminal opens to run the application.

However when the app crashes the terminal automatically closes and I cannot see the error.

Is there any way to keep the terminal open as if I would have launch the app from terminal ?

thanks

Comment: What app are you using exactly?

Comment: why ? is that relevant ? VTK

Comment: Well, I suppose the software *might* have an option for this, and that should be the first thing to check for.

Comment: well if I run it from terminal, obviously I don't have such issue. The software doesn't automatically closes, so the software is fine.

Comment: The point is that the terminal window closing the the app closing if it is launched by double-clicking a file from the Desktop.

Comment: I understand that. I was just offering a potential reason why JNK asked, doubled up as a minor suggestion. I'm not sure why you seem surprised that someone asked what the software was, as it's very common for Super Users to ask for additional details on questions.

Comment: Ok. Yeah but indeed it is not relevant right ?

Comment: Apparently not, but I don't know the software in question myself, so can't really comment. But personally I think every "unknown" factor of a problem makes it generally harder to answer, so any question that helps make the question more precise is generally useful.

Comment: yeah but indeed I never said it was a wrong question if you read above. You interpreted my "suprise". Anyway thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if I want to double-click a terminal `EXE` and not miss the result, I will build a simple batch file in the same folder to double-click.

```
fileToRun
pause
```

It runs the requested file and then you get a `please press any key to continue` after the program terminates (successfully or in error) to allow you to determine when to close the terminal.

Or, if you don't want to have to always manually close your terminal windows, you can configure your batch to dump the output to a file instead - that way you have easy access to *all* of the output after a crash. You do this like so (note that a 2nd run of the program will overwrite the file of a previous run).

```
fileToRun > fileToRunLOG.txt
```

**In your case**, create the batch file (adding a `%1` after `fileToRun` to handle the file argument!) and then associate the file type with the batch, not the main executable. Done.

This *might* be a bit indirect, but I've just come up with it, so you may wish to wait for some better suggestions...

Comment: I got it. But I cannot do it, and it is a long story. Shortly, I'm using VMWare to emulate Windows and I'm opening files from the underlying Operating System (Sharing folders). This only works from GUI and not from terminal. Is it clear ?

Comment: So, in other terms, if I create a batch file, I have the same issue.. I have to specify both app to use and file to open into the batch file and it doesn't work because the file cannot be found.

Comment: Did you use the `%1` argument specifier in your batch - eg `fileToRun %1` - to pass the argument given to the batch (ie the file you clicked on) on to the given program? If so, then I'm afraid I can't help much further as I've no idea how VMWare handles it's shared folders in this kind of setup.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the CMD.EXE shell or a terminal like PuTTY?

If you're using CMD.EXE, you can use the /K option to keep the window open after the command has completed.

Comment: uhm, I'm just double-clicking on a file. The app is only running in terminal.